# How to select label without having to change id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm at coding a form and have these chekboxes here:

```
 <div class="thumb1" >
       <label for="ltype"><img class="img" src="images/my1.jpg"  /></label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="chk"   name="ltype[]" id="ltype" value="word" required /><hr> <center><p><strong>Word Mark Logo</strong>
 </div>

 <div class="thumb1" >
      <label for="letter"><img class="img" src="images/my2.jpg"  /></label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk"   name="ltype[]"  id="ltype" value="letter" /><hr> <center><p><strong>Letter Mark Logo</strong></p></center>
 </div>

 <div class="thumb1">
      <label for="emblerm"><img class="img" src="images/my3.jpg"  /></label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk"   name="ltype[]" id="ltype" value="emblerm" /><hr> <center><p><strong>Emblerm Logo</strong></p></center>
 </div>
```

The problem is this i need that the image over my checkboxes be selectable if i click over  them without changing the id of my checkboxes the id have to be the same because of a javascript code. What can I use instead of  the `<label for="">` tag ?

Why the same id watch this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function logotype() {
    var group = document.newlogo.ltype;
    for (var i=0; i<group.length; i++) {
        if (group[i].checked)
            break;
    }
    if (i==group.length)
        return alert("Please select 1 to 3 Logo Types");
}
</script>
```

Any idea thanks in advance

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java, has it ?

Comment: ID should be unique. Also, you are using old markup, center tag is deprecated.

Comment: may has a java answer :)

Comment: @NewLogo do you mean javascript? java != javascript

Comment: @NewLogo as mentioned id's must be unique, what ever you maybe will work, but you this is not the way

Comment: can we do something with that java script code that blocks me from changing the ids ? but in the same time to be functional as with that script ?

Comment: What does `image selectable` even mean? Issue is not clear at all

Comment: [selectable = clickable = cheked chekbox]  :)

Comment: Try use "parent" selecting the input by indice: var input = document.getElementsByName('ltype[]')[0]; But the correct is that id should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems here..

First off ID's are suppose to be unique therefore if you use an ID and are dynamically manipulating it such as style. That style will apply to the other ID's.

My suggestion is use classes. If you're code doesn't work with classes then make it work!

This is all the help you're getting from me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("label").on('click', function() {
    $(this).children("img").toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

img {
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(102, 170, 255, 0);
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(102, 170, 255, 0);
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(102, 170, 255, 0);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(102, 170, 255, 0);
}

.active {
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(102, 170, 255, 0);
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(102, 170, 255, 0);
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(102, 170, 255, 0);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(102, 170, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.1/normalize.css'/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<label for="img1">
  <img src="http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=R2skhroaNe%2b865q6n9cxDoQg60f3G4ZX2nb4KUkCPmolQ&w=135&h=135&c=7&rs=1&qlt=90&pid=1.9">
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="img1">

<label for="img2">
  <img src="http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=RhpQjwU5DUZo1Rw%2fsJyaoZA1ffuNKdpTJ%2bT5pQkMTbjUQ&w=135&h=135&c=7&rs=1&qlt=90&pid=1.9">
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="img2">

<label for="img3">
  <img src="http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=RVifPWx3AufqCw21DOl1YjwlZlAmWOIenplPjQ8AalonA&w=135&h=135&c=7&rs=1&qlt=90&pid=1.9">
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="img3">

<label for="img4">
  <img src="http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=RgqVmxiIgHNkWlfImUiZBYg4Kg5hrQ0vW3pKcpUsOcQZQ&w=135&h=135&c=7&rs=1&qlt=90&pid=1.9">
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="img4">
```